# Query with Gaia: I have a list of 1000+ source_id's. How do I find the associated stars and their data?

Tags: data-analysis, identify-this-object, gaia, raw-data

I have a table of around 1700 source id's from gaiadr2 (in csv format). I would like to see the data that Gaia has for each star in a new table. I'm really struggling to figure out how to do this query, any help would be very much appreciated!

I do know that I can upload my table user_name.table1 to the Gaia archive, but how I access this in the query for crossmatching... can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: My response to [this](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/46892/query-gaia-by-star-name/46914#46914) question may be of help. I literally just posted it and not going to repeat it here.

Answer (score 1):

Something along these lines might work:

```
select *
from gaiadr2.gaia_source as gaia
join user_name.table1 as user
  on gaia.source_id = user.source_id
```